# Some probelm when I use client-go for kubernetes watch list

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I have some when I use the code in StackOverflow. Such as

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/pkg/api/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/pkg/fields"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

var (
    kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "./config", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    watchlist := cache.NewListWatchFromClient(clientset.Core().RESTClient(), "services", v1.NamespaceDefault,
        fields.Everything())
    _, controller := cache.NewInformer(
        watchlist,
        &v1.Service{},
        time.Second * 0,
        cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
            AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
                fmt.Printf("service added: %s \n", obj)
            },
            DeleteFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
                fmt.Printf("service deleted: %s \n", obj)
            },
            UpdateFunc:func(oldObj, newObj interface{}) {
                fmt.Printf("service changed \n")
            },
        },
    )
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    go controller.Run(stop)
    for{
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

it have some errors:

1. i can not find the package `"k8s.io/client-go/pkg/api/v1"` and `"k8s.io/client-go/pkg/fields"`, i don't know how to find it:

   https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go
2. the code

```
watchlist := cache.NewListWatchFromClient(clientset.Core().RESTClient(), "services", v1.NamespaceDefault,
        fields.Everything())
```

has the error:

> Cannot use 'clientSet.CoreV1().RESTClient()' (type rest.Interface) as
>   type Getter Type does not implement 'Getter' as some methods are
>   missing: Get() *restclient.Request

Could anyone tell me how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those imports don't look right. Look at the examples here: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples

Comment: yes, kubernetes has meraged some client-go api into it's api, but i can not find out how to do watch-list functions.

Comment: This is the ClientSet doc: https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes#Clientset. You can call ClientSet.CoreV1(), and from that, you can get one of the getter interfaces, and call the Watch API to watch a resource.

Comment: emm.. I have a try. it seem to be a client-go version problem.